# Watching porn for sexual desires? parents not marrying

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh

I am a medical student of 3rd year MBBS, from a wealthy family (By Allah grace), but my parents are not doing my marriage. I have agreed upon their choice but still, as you know sexual material is easily available on the Internet as sex is a human need what if I committed Zina? Or watch sexual material and ejaculate, will my parents be responsible for sins? Please guide me.

Comment: It seems you are male so why don't you look for a wife, why should your parents do this for you? you are mature and should be responsible for your choices!

Answer (score 0):

```
                                  بسم الله الرحمن الرحیم
```

I intend to elucidate the issue based on what I’ve perceived according to Islam plus my conclusion/assumption, as follows:

Briefly speaking, it is the duty of parents to supply the condition of marriage for their children –in appropriate age--, but, if I’m not mistaken, if they don’t do their obligation – and e.g. the purposed child commits sin – subsequently the parents will be partner (as the direct/indirect causer) in the sin(s), but it doesn’t mean that the child is free to commit sins, otherwise he/she’ll be another partner in the sin (or even as the main one), since anyhow s/he is not forced to do sin whereas he/she has option as free-will.

Hence, the child should not deceive himself/herself by (just) accusing the parents owing to … consequently, either the child or the parents who have not done their responsible properly/completely --in mentioned issue-- can be partners in the sin.

---

**Reference:**

[http://www.hawzah.net](http://%20%20http://www.hawzah.net/fa/Book/View/45322/34372/%D9%81%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%87%D9%85-%DA%A9%D8%B1%D8%AF%D9%86-%D9%85%D9%82%D8%AF%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%A7%D8%B2%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%AC)